# Is delete *p an alternative to delete [] p?

Tags: c++, arrays

The following code is from [the Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/new-operator-cpp?view=vs-2019)

```
int (**p) () = new (int (*[7]) ());
delete *p;
```

I think that `delete [] p` should be used here instead.

Is `delete *p` the same as `delete [] p`?

Comment: `delete *p` differs from `delete [] p`.

Comment: You're right. They're not the same.

Comment: `typedef` would make thing clearer.

Comment: Anyway `p[0]` is not initialized. They have typo.

Comment: `delete[]` what was `new[]`ed and `delete` what was `new`ed. Though in modern code you should avoid most uses of `new`, it's no longer the preferred way of dynamically creating objects. See `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared` instead or use a standard container.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That code is invalid C++, because only pointers-to-objects can be deleted. `*p` has type `int (*)()`, which is a function pointer, not a pointer to an object.

Even MSVC itself does not compile it, even in permissive mode:

```
error C2541: 'delete': cannot delete objects that are not pointers
```

They should have used `delete []` instead.

Comment: In what context one may need to dynamically allocate pointers to functions?

Comment: @Ayxan That would be another question, but for instance you may want to have a list of arbitrary operations to execute.

Comment: @Ayxan I have quickly posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55524710/9305398

Comment: Even though this is specific to MSVC, g++ gives the following similar error when trying to compile: `error: cannot delete expression of type 'int (*)()'` .. seems odd that MS would have missed something that simple in their docs :/